# Unity crash in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, 14.04, crash

After logging in to my account, I see no panels or anything else, only the background. I cannot even start a terminal with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>. The only thing the system responds to is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> which shows the system monitor (without the top panel) or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to login by hand. However logging in to the guest session works fine.

When logging in by hand I cannot restart unity (unity --replace), this gives me:

```
unknown job: unity-panel-service
```

Without the graphics display open I cannot reset compiz and unity to default settings. Searching other questions I tried to move the .Xauthority in ~/ to some other place. Did not work. I also tried the `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` and `sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity` +rebooting. Also tried to reinstall `lightdm`. Nothing works.

I've been running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS just fine for quite some time and haven't recently done any changes besides installing updates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

Answer (score 11):

So I finally managed to recover by doing the following

`mv ~/.config/dconf/user ~/.config/dconf/user.old`

This makes me loose all my settings, but at least I can log in and now I can attempt at recovering at least some of the settings from the `user.old` file.

Comment: The solution is so simple, yet so strange :) Exactly what I was looking for, although I tried 50 other things

Comment: Unfortunately this file is a binary file, so there's no way to restore single values from it. However, it brought me back the desktop after deleting it.

Comment: I thought I have to reinstall ubuntu again.. huge thanks