# Cannot login after turn on Window spread in Unity Tweak Tool

Tags: 14.04, unity, login

I'm now using **Ubuntu 14.04.3** and using **Unity** tool for change some effects. Curiously, I changed **Window spread** to "on" in the Window spread tag, the system automatically logged out. When I tried to login, I entered the main screens but immediately the system logged out again. After efforts login few times, the situation still happened.

However, I login successfully with a **Guest** account. I tried some solutions on the Internet but there is no point to solve my problem. What should I do?

Comment: Could this help?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read this thread: [Unity crash in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468656/unity-crash-in-ubuntu-14-04?rq=1)

After all, I resolved this problem by typing

```
mv ~/.config/dconf/user ~/.config/dconf/user.old
```

I followed this tips, they changed back to the default Ubuntu settings. Although it isn't the best solution, it worked fine for me. Thanks everyone taking time to help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to console (tty1)
2. Login
3. Check the running dbus-deamon

   ```
   ps aux | grep dbus-deamon
   ```
4. Set X display & dbus address variables

   ```
   export DISPLAY=:0
   export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-bN5xD2OA1Y
   ```

   `/tmp/dbus-bN5xD2OA1Y` set as example, copy your own from previous step.
5. Run this to get the enabled Compiz plug-ins

   ```
   dconf read /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/active-plugins
   ```

   Output should be something like:

   ```
   ['core', 'composite', 'opengl', 'compiztoolbox', 'grid', 'wall', 'vpswitch', 'snap', 'mousepoll', 'copytex', 'commands', 'place', 'move', 'regex', 'resize', 'imgpng', 'unitymtgrabhandles', 'session', 'animation', 'fade', 'expo', 'workarounds', 'ezoom', 'unityshell', 'scale']
   ```
6. Then this after you remove `scale` plug-in the for window spread, example:

   ```
   dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/active-plugins "['core', 'composite', 'opengl', 'compiztoolbox', 'grid', 'wall', 'vpswitch', 'snap', 'mousepoll', 'copytex', 'commands', 'place', 'move', 'regex', 'resize', 'imgpng', 'unitymtgrabhandles', 'session', 'animation', 'fade', 'expo', 'workarounds', 'ezoom', 'unityshell']"
   ```

   However, I noticed from your output in chat that you have gnome compatibility plugin enabled `'gnomecompat',` which is not compatible with unity plugin. (from a previous experience, it make unity crash)
7. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> to switch to back to GUI console (tty7)

**Note:** As retyping such long command in terminal is error prune, I wrote a script to do same instructions

```
wget -O au_699540.sh http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=swuzDuJ3
chmod +x au_699540.sh
./au_699540.sh
```

---

I don't want to make it long for you. There is another quick trick but ***it has a drawback***. It will reset all your user settings stored in `dconf` database (This includes Unity, Gnome & Some GTK apps)

```
sudo rm ~/.config/dconf/user
```

Comment: This is not working. It came up with this error -
error: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
Usage:
    dconf write KEY VALUE
Write a new value to a key
Arguments:
   KEY            A key path (starting, but not ending with '/')
   VALUE       The value to write (in GVariant format)

Comment: No I already tried that, but it was of no use.

Comment: Yes I have lightdm

Comment: Yes, no issue with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32240/discussion-between-sneetsher-and-priyansh).

Answer (score 0):

maybe [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454576/cant-login-to-ubuntu-14-04-after-upgrade) can help you to login, after this you can reset compiz to default with this command:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

Comment: Sorry coming up with error message.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the tty, and enter this in th tty:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install dkms
sudo dkms-reconfigure unity
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: Sorry but even this is not working

Comment: Have you tried this sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity, and then this unity --replace-reset-icon & disown, and it might work fine this way.

Comment: There is no problem with unity. They all suggested this me to do before.

Answer (score 0):

Reset Unity, wiping all changes to configuration.

1. Swtich to a tty console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>)
2. Login
3. `unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity`
4. `sudo reboot`

Comment: Sorry, this is not helping.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, to bring up a **tty**. The type **username** and **password**. Then:

Install `dconf-tools: sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`

Reset `Compiz and Unity: dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`

Reset Unity: `setsid unity`

If that also fails, then maybe deleting the settings files might help:

```
rm  -rf ~/.compiz-1 
rm -rf ~/.config/compiz-1
```

Lastly, you could try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
unity --reset-icons
```